# alternate background color for tablix in aggregate/sum in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

I have to implement alternate background color for the rows retrieved by report but the problem is it has aggregate / sum functions and does not work properly so I used the code below -

```
Private bOddRow As Boolean 
'************************************************* ************************ 
' -- Display green-bar type color banding in detail rows 
' -- Call from BackGroundColor property of all detail row textboxes 
' -- Set Toggle True for first item, False for others. 
'************************************************* ************************ 
Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, _ 
ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean) As String 
If Toggle Then bOddRow = Not bOddRow 
If bOddRow Then 
Return OddColor 
Else 
Return EvenColor 
End If 
End Function 
' 
Function RestartColor(ByVal OddColor As String) As String 
bOddRow = True 
Return OddColor 
End Function
```

So I have three different kinds of cell backgrounds now:

1. First column of data row has =Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True) (This is the same as the previous answer.)
2. Remaining columns of data row have =Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False) (This, also, is the same as the previous answer.)

What i do not understand is why make it true for first column and false for rest? any help would be really appreciated.

Also the code above functions the same with or without the following (which again i do not understand)

```
' 
Function RestartColor(ByVal OddColor As String) As String 
bOddRow = True 
Return OddColor 
End Function
```

I got this code from another forum and I am new to SSRS and VB. Kindly help please.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The "Toggle" property should only be set to True once per row: this means that the function will switch (toggle) the color that it returns.

So if you call these in this order, this code does this:

`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "White"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "White"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "White"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "White"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "White"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", True)` returns "White"
`=Code.RestartColor("AliceBlue")` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "AliceBlue"
`=Code.AlternateColor("AliceBlue", "White", False)` returns "AliceBlue"

So any calls to AlternateColor with toggle = False will return the same color as the last call. Any calls with toggle = true will switch to the other color.

RestartColor sets back to a starting point: maybe you always want the top row of every instance of a grouping to be shaded the same color.